I can't find a precise answer for this error Chat imported from Telelgram bot
ImportError: cannot import name 'Chat' from 'telegram' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/telegram/init.py)
How can I overcome this error?
!pip install python-telegram
!pip install telegram
!pip install telegram.chat



import time
import requests
import logging
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackContext
from telegram.error import TelegramError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from telegram import Bot, Chat


https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#why-am-i-getting-importerror-cannot-import-name-xy-from-telegram

@CallMeStag   I checked the link and did as guided but the error is still there even after installing the python-telegram-bot only
